# Trouble getting ubuntu, nginx and ruby on rails application running. Error 500 and no log output

Tags: ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, unicorn

I am having a getting my rails application up and running with nginx and unicorn. None of the different parts are printing out an error.

Here is what I currently have in the way of configurations:

unicorn.rb - https://gist.github.com/vmcilwain/4140686c2d84b2f3c577

nginx site - https://gist.github.com/vmcilwain/9d7d42e2986b08a223b9

I am pretty stumped on what else I can try. I have not found much online since I don't really know what is causing the error.

If it helps, the last error I got was that the upstream couldn't find the socket that unicorn created. The location was originally /tmp. I decided to move it to the rails applications tmp/sockets directory. That made the most sense to me.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure unicorn is running with the right config file? No log output sounds suspicious...

Comment: Hi @rossta, I am sure it is running with the right unicorn config. I have double checked it several times. Here is what my unicorn init file looks like just in case I may have missed something: https://gist.github.com/vmcilwain/e91b024161716cd8466b